# Angular - data not loading without manual refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, angular-ui-router

I have a component which imports two models, an `Application` model and a `DataType` model. One application can have many datatypes. The purpose of this component is to handle a form for adding a new application with datatypes which are selected from a dropdown list. The Angular app uses REST calls to create such objects. In the back-end, Application is one table, DataTypes is another table, and `Application_DataTypes` is the third (linking) table. The way it works is I am calling a GET method to retrieve and list all of the datatypes so they can be selected. Once the `application_name` and `description` are filled out, and datatypes are selected, a POST method is called for the application, I receive the response with the object id, name, and description. Then I make a second POST call to `application_datatypes` that is nested within the response of the application post. I do this so that I can retrieve the `application_id` and use it when inserting into the `application_datatypes` linking table. Once the Save button is clicked the application is routed back to a page that has a list of all of the applications and their details. Everything works as intended except that **after the Save button is clicked and the List of Applications is displayed, the datatypes are blank until a manual refresh or f5 is done.**

Relevant code of `application.component.ts`

```
this.applicationService.createApplication(this.username, this.application).subscribe (
  response => {
    this.newApplication = Object.values(response)[0];
    this.applicationDataTypes.forEach(item => {
      if (item.checked) {
        this.appData = new AppData({appId: Object.values(response)[0], dataTypeId: item.dataTypeId});
        this.appDatas.push(this.appData);
      }
     });

    this.appDatas.forEach(item => {
      this.applicationService.createAppDataType(this.username, item).subscribe (
        data => console.log(data)
      );
    });
  },
  data => console.log(data),
);
this.router.navigate([`main-content/${this.userName}/destList`]);
```

The entire code for `application.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppData } from '../models/app-data.model';
import { ApplicationDataType } from '../models/application-data-type.model';
import { Application } from '../models/application.model';
import { Datatype } from '../models/datatype.model';
import { BasicAuthenticationService } from '../service/basic-authentication.service';
import { ApplicationDataService } from '../service/data/application-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-application',
  templateUrl: './application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private applicationService: ApplicationDataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
    private basicAuthenticationService: BasicAuthenticationService) { }

  username: string;
  appId: number;
  dataTypeId: number;
  application: Application;
  appData: AppData;
  appDatas: AppData[];
  datatypes: Datatype[];
  checkedDatatypes: Datatype[];
  hide = true;
  exists = false;
  appDataId;
  applicationDataType: ApplicationDataType;
  applicationDataTypes: ApplicationDataType[];
  newApplication: number;
  userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
  isApplicationInvalid = false;
  WarningMessage = 'Application Name and Description must be filled out!';

  counter = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    this.appId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.application = new Application(this.appId, '', '', '');
    this.applicationDataTypes =  [];
    this.appDatas = [];

    // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
    if (this.appId != 0) {
      this.applicationService.retrieveApplication(this.username, this.appId).subscribe(
        data => this.application = data
      );

      this.applicationService.retreiveAllDataTypesByAppId(this.username, this.appId).subscribe(
        data => this.checkedDatatypes = data
      );

      this.applicationService.retreiveAllDatatypes(this.username).subscribe(
        data => this.datatypes = data
      );
    }

    this.applicationService.retreiveAllDatatypes(this.username).subscribe(
      data => this.datatypes = data
    );
  }

  getDatatypes = () => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
    if (this.counter == 0) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
      if (this.appId != 0){
        this.datatypes.forEach(item => {
          this.applicationDataType = new ApplicationDataType(this.route.snapshot.params.id, item.dataTypeId, item.description, false);
          const datatype = this.checkedDatatypes.find(y => y.description === item.description);
          if (datatype) {
            this.applicationDataType.checked = true;
            this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
          } else {
            this.applicationDataType.checked = false;
            this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.datatypes.forEach(item => {
          this.applicationDataType = new ApplicationDataType(this.route.snapshot.params.id, item.dataTypeId, item.description, false);
          this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
        });
      }
      this.counter ++;
    }
  }

  uncheck = dataType => {
    const index = this.applicationDataTypes.indexOf(dataType);
    this.applicationDataTypes[index].checked = !this.applicationDataTypes[index].checked;
  }

  saveApplication = () => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
    if (this.application.appName != '' && this.application.appDesc != '') {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
      if (this.appId == 0) {
        this.applicationService.createApplication(this.username, this.application).subscribe (
          response => {
            this.newApplication = Object.values(response)[0];
            this.applicationDataTypes.forEach(item => {
              if (item.checked) {
                this.appData = new AppData({appId: Object.values(response)[0], dataTypeId: item.dataTypeId});
                this.appDatas.push(this.appData);
              }
             });

            this.appDatas.forEach(item => {
              this.applicationService.createAppDataType(this.username, item).subscribe (
                data => console.log(data)
              );
            });
          },
          data => console.log(data),
        );
      }
      else {
        this.applicationService.updateApplication(this.username, this.appId, this.application).subscribe (
          data => console.log(data)
        );

        this.applicationDataTypes.forEach(item => {
          if (item.checked) {
            if (!this.checkedDatatypes.find(z => z.description === item.datatypeDescription)){
              this.appData = new AppData({appId: this.appId, dataTypeId: item.dataTypeId});
              this.appDatas.push(this.appData);
            }
          }
         });

        this.appDatas.forEach(item => {
          this.applicationService.createAppDataType(this.username, item).subscribe (
            data => console.log(data)
          );
        });

        this.applicationDataTypes.forEach(item => {
          if (!item.checked) {
            if (this.checkedDatatypes.find(z => z.description === item.datatypeDescription)){
              this.applicationService.deleteAppDataType(this.username, this.appId, item.dataTypeId).subscribe(
                response => {
                  console.log(response);
                }
              );
            }
          }
         });
      }
      this.router.navigate([`main-content/${this.userName}/destList`]);
    }
    else {
      this.isApplicationInvalid = true;
    }
  }

  CancelAction = () => {
    this.router.navigate([`main-content/${this.userName}/destList`]);
  }

  onHomePage = () => this.router.navigate([`main-content/${this.userName}/home`]);
}
```

applications.component.ts - This is the component that displays the list of applications with their details.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalService } from '../../modal/modal.service';
import { Application } from '../../models/application.model';
import { Datatype } from '../../models/datatype.model';
import { BasicAuthenticationService } from '../../service/basic-authentication.service';
import { ApplicationDataService } from '../../service/data/application-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applications',
  templateUrl: './applications.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applications.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationsComponent implements OnInit {

  applications: Application[];
  datatypes: Datatype[];
  username: string;
  message: string;
  groupId = localStorage.getItem('groupId');
  appDeleteId: number;

  constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationDataService,
              private router: Router,
              private basicAuthenticationService: BasicAuthenticationService,
              private modalService: ModalService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshApplications();
    this.username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();
  }

  refreshApplications = () => {
    this.username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    this.applicationService.retreiveAllApplications(this.username).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.applications = response;
      }
    );
  }

  deleteApplication = appId => {
    console.log(`delete app ${appId}`);

    this.applicationService.deleteApplication(this.username, appId).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.message = `Application ${appId} was Successfully Deleted!`;
        this.refreshApplications();
      }
    );
  }

  updateApplication = appId => {
    console.log(`update app ${appId}`);
    this.router.navigate(['applications', appId]);
    this.applicationService.retreiveAllDataTypesByAppId(this.username, appId).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.datatypes = response;
      }
    );
  }

  openModal = (id, appId) => {
    this.modalService.open(id);
    this.appDeleteId = appId;
  }

  closeModal = (id, confDelete) => {
    this.modalService.close(id);
    if (confDelete) {
      this.deleteApplication(this.appDeleteId);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m presuming the destList route is the page that shows the list of applications? And that page isn’t refreshing? If so then then can you show the code for that page too?

Comment: You are presuming correctly, and it is refreshing but only with the Application id, name, and description but not the datatypes

Comment: @Luke.T I added the code you requested.